# Create custom pipe that is async by itself

Tags: angular

I've created a custom pipe that retrieves bits of textual content from an API, like this:

```typescript
@Pipe({ name: 'apiText' })
export class ApiTextPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private myApiService: MyApiService) {
  }

  transform(key: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.myApiService.getText(key);
  }
}
```

I have to use it like this:

```html
<strong>{{'some-key' | apiText | async}}</strong>
```

But effectively I will *always* want to combine the `apiText` and `async` pipes. I'd prefer to write this:

```html
<strong>{{'some-key' | apiTextAsync}}</strong>
```

Can I do that somehow, and make things a bit more DRY by combining the two pipes?

---

**UPDATE 1**: I've [opened a GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32368) as a feature request for a solution for this.

**UPDATE 2**: The issue was closed because [the async pipe "is not special" and "nothing prevents you from writing one that is similar](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32368#issuecomment-527672368) ‍♂️

Comment: Maybe you should check how async pipe works? You basicly wants to extend its functionality.

Comment: From what I have seen async pipe subscribes itself and returns latest emitted value with additional logic to resubscribing in case of input change. IDK if it is worth of reimplementing.

Comment: `{{'some-key' | apiText | async}}` is far easier to understand and far less source code to maintain.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/503a524d276d14a8214baa8afb66f6390694ca48/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts
 --- There's the source for `AsyncPipe`. You can import it somewhere and extend it, but as @cgTag has mentioned, it's generallybad practice to duplicate functionality, especially when pipes are meant to have a limited and clear scope of functionality.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. I came to the same conclusion as the one I read above, and have tried to formulate it as an answer for others to see. (And perhaps at some point someone will provide a competing answer to show us another way.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Several commenters pointed out (rightfully so) that this violates SRP and might hurt readability. But even though that'll make me reconsider whether I *want* this, I still for sure wanted to know how to do it *if* you want it. I found two solutions (with help from commenters, again).

**Composition** (not recommended)

Create your own internal `AsyncPipe` and use it. Here's a base setup that should work:

```typescript
@Pipe({ name: 'apiText', pure: false })
export class ApiTextPipe implements PipeTransform, OnDestroy {
  private asyncPipe: AsyncPipe;

  constructor(private myApiService: MyApiService, private injector: Injector) {
    this.asyncPipe = new AsyncPipe(injector.get(ChangeDetectorRef));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
     this.asyncPipe.ngOnDestroy();
  }

  transform(key: string): string {
    return this.asyncPipe.transform(this.myApiService.getText(key));
  }
}
```

In addition to the abovementioned downsides (noted by commenters), I see other issues:

- If ever the AsyncPipe changes, e.g. it starts implementing `OnInit`, then our own pipe also needs to change. And you will likely miss this. It's not good that our pipe's implementation is coupled in this way to the AsyncPipe.
- I couldn't seem to get `AsyncPipe` injected because it relies on the special `ChangeDetectorRef`, so I used [this suggested approach](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14656#issuecomment-281829953) asking it directly from the injector. (There's likely a better way to do this, but I'm not digging further for now...)

**Inheritance** (not recommended)

You could also try to `extends AsyncPipe` in your own pipe, but that route lies even more awkward code that tightly couples your pipe to the async pipe. Some problems with that approach when I tried it:

- You again need a `ChangeDetectorRef` to pass to the `super(...)` call
- You need to tightly couple to the signature of the `transform` method from the `AsyncPipe`
- The `transform` gets super complicated as it no longer just takes a string (see the previous point)
- Unknown to me if this properly makes Angular call the super class's `ngOnDestroy` method

Plus whatever else I forgot. The code I had felt so icky that it doesn't seem wise to even share it.

**Duplicate the Source** (not recommended?)

As one of the commenters suggested, [the source for `AsyncPipe`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/503a524d276d14a8214baa8afb66f6390694ca48/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts) is open. So you could take that and build your own pipe from that.

This is not a wise decision in my opinion and I'd recommend *against* it, but [it *is* the solution recommended by the Angular team on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32368#issuecomment-527672368).

**Stick with double pipes** (the only decent option?)

So doing `{{'some-key' | apiText | async}}` and always using two pipes, seems to be the only somewhat reasonable option currently.

Comment: I'm going to cry a little: If i use the ```{{ variable | customPipe | async }}``` my template would be more complex than if I use a ```customPipeAsync```, I have a dynamic table who fill with a list of columns each one have a pipe to modify the cells values, my best option would be to add ```customPipeAsync``` to the pipes of the corresponding colls

Comment: I think the example you provided is wrong. this.asyncPipe.transform(..) will return null. :/ Can you elaborate?

Comment: You mean the "Composition (not recommended)" example? Afraid I cannot elaborate, as I never went down that actual path. If you have chosen that approach and encountered an issue with it, I recommend creating a new question with a minimal repro. Good luck!

Answer (score 9):

There's no need to duplicate the source of the `async` pipe-transform, the only things you really need are the `pure: false` property and the `ChangeDetectorRef`.

Here is a small minimal example for it:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'example',
  pure: false
})
export class ExamplePipeTransform implements PipeTransform {

  value?: string;

  constructor(private _ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  transform(value: any): unknown {

    if (!this.value) {
      this.value = value;

      // Just an example for some async operation:
      setTimeout(() => {
        // In the callback do this:
        this.value = value;
        this._ref.markForCheck();
      }, 1000);
    }

    return this.value;
  }
}
```

Once the asynchronous operation you want to do is done, you store the value and simply call `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck`. This will cause `transform` to be called again.

The `setTimeout` here is just an example, instead you could do an `Observable.subscribe` and then return the resolved value.

Comment: But... then you miss out on _all_ the extra features and robustness of the built-in `AsyncPipe`, non?

Comment: @Jeroen seems like it is ok when you don't need them)

Comment: True, for sure. Though I personally think that nearly all parts of the built-in async pipe are _essential_, and that the code from this answer will lead to bugs for your user in many real world scenarios.

Comment: @Jeroen No, I know the source of the built-in AsyncPipe very well and it does not do anything special. The code from this answer will lead to no bugs, it in fact does exactly the same as the original one except for not subscribing to promises/observables.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked / did what I needed it to!!!! Thank you so much

Comment: Thanks! This works. In my case I had to keep track of the timeout and clear it in `ngOnDestroy`, so the CD did't have to check destroyed views anymore. It wasn't even hundreds of them, but enough to crash my browser.